# Adding Controls Dynamically In ActionScriptand Access The Correct Instance

Tags: actionscript-3, dynamic

My question here is, I'm trying to understand exactly how this piece of code I wrote works. This does what I need, but not sure exactly what is going on behind the scenes. Can any ActionScript Pro's out there help??

So, what I'm doing is adding buttons and datagrids dynamically while iterating through a for loop. The button controls the visibility of the canvas containing a datagrid by setting the visible property to false and removing the canvas from the layout.

If I create a function that adds a button and an event listener that sets the visible properties, the button is associated with the correct canvas. If I do not add the button and the event listener in function, the all the buttons control the last canvas added in the for loop.

Does this have something to do with closure? See code below.

This Works:

```
 for(var j:int = 0; j < resultsArray.length; j++)
 {      
   var dataGridCanvas:Canvas = new Canvas();
   dataGridCanvas.top = 5;

   var vboxDatagrid:VBox = new VBox();
   var vboxButton:VBox = new VBox();

   var resultsAttributeDataGrid:DataGrid = new DataGrid();

   vboxButton.addChild(addButtonToCanvas(identifyResults[0], dataGridCanvas));

   sidePanel.idResults.vbxIdToolIResults.addChild(vboxButton);

   var vboxDataGridChild:VBox = new VBox();

   vboxDataGridChild.addChild(resultsAttributeDataGrid);

   vboxDatagrid.addChild(vboxDataGridChild);

   dataGridCanvas.addChild(vboxDatagrid);

   idResults.vbxIdToolIResults.addChild(dataGridCanvas);
 }

 private function addButtonToCanvas(layerName:String, theCanvas:Canvas):VBox
 {
    var vbox:VBox = new VBox();

    var layerButton:spark.components.Button = new spark.components.Button();
            layerButton.label = layerName as String;

            layerButton.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, 
                function onClick():void{ 
                    theCanvas.visible == true ?         theCanvas.visible = false : theCanvas.visible = true;
                    theCanvas.visible == false ? theCanvas.includeInLayout = false : theCanvas.includeInLayout = true
                });

    vbox.addChild(layerButton);

       return vbox;
}
```

This does not work, but is doing the same thing - adding a button and it's event listener to a vbox:

```
 for(var j:int = 0; j < resultsArray.length; j++)
 {      
   var dataGridCanvas:Canvas = new Canvas();
   dataGridCanvas.top = 5;

   var vboxDatagrid:VBox = new VBox();
   var vboxButton:VBox = new VBox();

   var resultsAttributeDataGrid:DataGrid = new DataGrid();

   var vbox:VBox = new VBox();

   var layerButton:spark.components.Button = new spark.components.Button();

   layerButton.label = layerName as String;

   layerButton.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, 
                function onClick():void{ 
                    dataGridCanvas.visible == true ?             dataGridCanvas.visible = false : dataGridCanvas.visible = true;
                    dataGridCanvas.visible == false ? dataGridCanvas.includeInLayout = false : dataGridCanvas.includeInLayout = true
                });

   vbox.addChild(layerButton);

   sidePanel.idResults.vbxIdToolIResults.addChild(vbox);

   var vboxDataGridChild:VBox = new VBox();

   vboxDataGridChild.addChild(resultsAttributeDataGrid);

   vboxDatagrid.addChild(vboxDataGridChild);

   dataGridCanvas.addChild(vboxDatagrid);

   idResults.vbxIdToolIResults.addChild(dataGridCanvas);
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

It has *everything* to do with closures.

When you pass the Canvas to addButtonToCanvas in the first example, the closure keeps it associated with the onClick handler.